# How do I rewrite some lines in a file with new timestamps

Tags: python, powershell

I have a file that uses several different API versions of an application
In V1 of the API there are start and end timestamps in the string that always match the pattern

```
&startTimestamp=1572580801000&endTimestamp=1572667141000`
```

so a full url may look something like this (some data omitted for security)

```
curl -k -X GET "https://serverpathandurl/api/v1/path?query=SELECT%%20xxx%%2C%%20%%20count(xxx)%%20FROM%%20xxx%%20group%%20by%%20xxx&startTimestamp=1572580801000&endTimestamp=1572667141000&explain=false" -H "header " -H "header" > File
```

I have some lines in this file that do not have time stamps.
I run this file of CURL statements at the same time every day. 
So I know that it can always incremented by a fixed value of 86400000 for both the start and end time stamp

How do I loop through the file, modify the lines that have the new incremented values for start and end time stamps, and write the file with the same name?
I assume part of the issue is changing the string value and adding it the value as an intiger, and then reforming the string.

Here is an example of the file content with 3 entries

```
curl -k -X GET "https://serverpathandurl/api/v1/path?query=SELECT%%20xxx%%2C%%20%%20count(xxx)%%20FROM%%20xxx%%20group%%20by%%20xxx&startTimestamp=1572580801000&endTimestamp=1572667141000&explain=false" -H "header " -H "header" > File
curl -k -X GET "https://example2/api/v1/path?query=SELECT%%20xxx%%2C%%20%%20count(xxx)%%20FROM%%20xxx%%20group%%20by%%20xxx&startTimestamp=1572580801000&endTimestamp=1572667141000&explain=false" -H "header " -H "header" > File
curl -k -X GET "https://serverpathandurl/api/v2/metrics/series/xxx?resolution=INF&from=now-1d%%2Fm&scope=entity(xxx)" -H "headerionfo" -H "headerinfo" > file
```

Comment: Have you considered using a regex replace? I don't know Python, but it should be fairly simple with PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is for PowerShell.

The timestamps in the urls are Unix Milliseconds.

To replace the timestamps by adding one day (86400000) to them every day, you could do something like this:

```
$file  = 'D:\urls.txt'  # your file goes here
$lines = Get-Content -Path $file
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.Count; $i++) {
    if ($lines[$i] -match 'startTimestamp=(\d+)') {
        $newTimeStamp = 'startTimestamp={0}' -f ([int64]$matches[1] + 86400000)
        $lines[$i] = $lines[$i] -replace $matches[0], $newTimeStamp
    }
    if ($lines[$i] -match 'endTimestamp=(\d+)') {
        $newTimeStamp = 'endTimestamp={0}' -f ([int64]$matches[1] + 86400000)
        $lines[$i] = $lines[$i] -replace $matches[0], $newTimeStamp
    }
}

$lines | Set-Content -Path $file -Force
```

If you would like to be able to set your own start and end timestamps, you can play around with the following conversion methods:

To convert a Unix MilliSecond timestamp to datetime object:

```
$utcDate = [DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1572667141000).UtcDateTime    # gives you the date in UTC
```

or

```
$date = [DateTimeOffset]::FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(1572667141000).LocalDateTime  # gives you the date in Local time
```

To convert a DateTime object into a Unix millisecond timestamp:

```
# example uses the current date
[DateTime]$origin = [DateTime]::new(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'Utc')
[TimeSpan]$diff = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() - $origin
$unixTimeStamp  = [int64][Math]::Floor($diff.TotalMilliseconds)  # in MilliSeconds
```

In your example, the `startTimestamp` converts to `2019-11-01 04:00:01` and the `endTimestamp` converts to `2019-11-02 03:59:01` (Utc)
The difference between the startTimestamp and endTimestamp is 86340000 milliseconds (1 day minus 1 minute)

Comment: Thank you ! This is EXACTLY what I wanted to accomplish. So you are aware. I went back and reviewed some of the regular expressions functionality with $matches. This will help me in the future and I will try to build off the example you gave as much as possible .  Kindest regards!

Comment: @runatyr Thanks for the nice feedback!